# How to open a dialog box from a component with multiple templates?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component with multiple html files, each file is responsible for a content of a dialog box. I want to assign each html file to a collection of buttons. Using the following code opens the content of default file `message1.component.html`:

```
this.dialog.open(message1Component, {});
```

how to open `message2.component.html` located in the same component?

EDIT:

or should I use one `.html` file with multiple `<div>` tags inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular this can be handled with so told `dynamic components`. Here is your first component (message1Component in your case)

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic',
  template: `
   <div><img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/7294069/pexels-photo-7294069.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=350' alt='image'></div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
  :host {
    text-align: center;
  }`,
  ],
})
export class DynamicComponent {
}
```

and here **app.component.ts** which load the component (dialog in your case)

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DynamicComponent } from './dynamic.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('dynamic', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  private viewRef: ViewContainerRef;

  showDynamicComponent(): void {
    this.viewRef.clear();
    this.viewRef.createComponent(DynamicComponent);
  }

  removeDynamicComponent(): void {
    this.viewRef.clear();
  }
}
```

and its HTML:

```
<div class="buttons-container">
  <button class="show-btn" (click)="showDynamicComponent()">Show component</button>
  <button class="remove-btn" (click)="removeDynamicComponent()">
    Remove component
  </button>
</div>
<ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>
```

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mcbbub?file=src/app/app.component.html).

### Note

You can set 2/3 or more components into an array like:

```
dialogCompos = [comp1, comp2, comp3];
```

And then you can show it `this.viewRef.createComponent(dialogCompos[1]);`